# How do I check the reference counter of things in openCL?

Tags: reference, count, opencl, inspect

http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/

I don't understand how to check the reference count for say, an openCL context. How is it done? Is there a function call or field? I tried googling and I couldn't figure it out. I tried debugging and inspecting (using JOCL and Java) and I didn't see anything. Let me know.

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting down-voted and shunned for asking this question. I think there is something critical that I just don't understand and it would be nice to have a dialogue about that instead of being down-voted.

Comment: You got downvoted because this question is essentially a duplicate of a question you asked the previous day, which was mostly invalid and was itself a follow-up to another misguided question you asked less than an hour before. Instead of polluting SO and the opencl tag with duplicates, you should be editing your original question and using the comment system to ask for clarification of anything you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

You're not really supposed to read the reference counts, because the information would be meaningless. By the time the (hypothetical clReadReferenceCount_NOT_REAL) function returns and you'd get the reference count value, other threads may have incremented and/or decremented the reference count. The only way you're supposed to access the reference count is through glRetain*/clRelease* -functions, which are used for incrementing and decrementing only (not reading the value), like a semaphore in concurrent programming.

Comment: It has been useful to me to get the reference counters to understand, for instance, how they behave after coping objects. I can't make a correct answer in a Java context, but in C, that information can be retrieve using clGetContextInfo with CL_CONTEXT_REFERENCE_COUNT.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look clRetain*/clRelease* functions. I guess you were downvoted because they can be found very easily. It wasn't me though.